# "Enquire about whether" vs. "enquire whether"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, transitivity

> - I'm writing to you to enquire whether you have a need for
> - I'm writing to you to enquire about whether you have a need for

Which is proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is correct:

> I'm writing to you to enquire whether you have a need for...

The second option is grammatically odd, but in any case would imply you were asking not about the need, but about everything around that need. I can't think of a correct usage here.